# WPF DatePicker Popup Calendar Background Color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I style the background color of the popup / dropdown control of the default WPF DatePicker control?
I want to do this via xaml.

This does not work:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/fonts/#Titillium Web" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#777777" />
    </Style>
```

I assume that it does not target the right property.

This is how it currently looks. I want to change the white background to something readable.

[image: expanded DatePicker[1]]

Comment: It's a valid question - why would anyone -1 it without commentary? Sheesh.

Answer (score 1):

Try targeting DatePickerTextBox, like so:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#777777" />
</Style>
```

Comment: This only works for the TextBox. I want the background of the calendar.

Comment: Same idea, target Calendar.

Comment: Mind explaining how to get the calendar from the DatePicker control? This does not work: <Style TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#777777" />
</Style>

Comment: DatePicker is a little bit more complex than most controls.  But the short version is that there are several styles you might need to tweak:  CalendarButton for the month/year buttons, CalendarDayButton for the day buttons, and CalendarItem for the actual calendar control.  The properties of Calendar controlling their styles are, respectively, CalendarButtonStyle, CalendarDayButtonStyle, and CalendarItemStyle.  They can be set directly, or they can be set through the style property of Calendar.  I'd recommend looking over https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx for more detail.